# Django Rest Framework and JSONField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Given a Django model with a [JSONField](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield), what is the correct way of serializing and deserializing it using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)?

I've already tried crating a custom `serializers.WritableField` and overriding `to_native` and `from_native`:

```
from json_field.fields import JSONEncoder, JSONDecoder
from rest_framework import serializers

class JSONFieldSerializer(serializers.WritableField):
    def to_native(self, obj):
    return json.dumps(obj, cls = JSONEncoder)

    def from_native(self, data):
        return json.loads(data, cls = JSONDecoder)
```

But when I try to updating the model using `partial=True`, all the floats in the JSONField objects become strings.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you're using Django Rest Framework >= 3.3, then the JSONField serializer is [now included](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield).  This is now the correct way.

If you're using Django Rest Framework < 3.0, then see gzerone's answer.

If you're using DRF 3.0 - 3.2 AND you can't upgrade AND you don't need to serialize binary data, then follow these instructions.

First declare a field class:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class JSONSerializerField(serializers.Field):
    """ Serializer for JSONField -- required to make field writable"""
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value
```

And then add in the field into the model like

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    json_data = JSONSerializerField()
```

And, if you do need to serialize binary data, you can always the copy [official release code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/commit/10dbf1316f9092dbd751b1e47fbcab45576ca8fc#diff-af402f515db75c7c6754453cf15455d9R1526)

Answer (score 18):

In 2.4.x:

```
from rest_framework import serializers # get from https://gist.github.com/rouge8/5445149

class WritableJSONField(serializers.WritableField):
    def to_native(self, obj):
        return obj


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    my_json_field = WritableJSONField() # you need this.
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using JSONField as the classname because it would clash with the other class.

Comment: fixmycode, thanks for your suggestion on the classname. Hmm..., that just a sample code, which copied from https://gist.github.com/rouge8/5445149, so you can change it whatever you want. But @Tzach, 'JSONFieldSerializer' is not a suitable name for the subclass of the 'serializers.WritableField' I think. It looks like that JSONFieldSerializer and MyModelSerializer are the same things. Hope to hear your opinion.

Comment: Thanks @gzerone for your comment. I admit I didn't put too much attention for the new class name. Just wanted it not to cause clashes. Does `JSONWritableField` sounds better to you?

Comment: Or WritableJSONField, ;）

Comment: This is only valid for Django Rest Framework version 2. For version 3, see the answer by Mark Chackerian.

Comment: Yea, since Django 1.8 & DRF 3.x, I replaced WritableJSONField with ListField or DictField in my case, which works fine with postgres array fields.

Answer (score 6):

If and only if you know the first-level style of your JSON content (List or Dict), you can use DRF builtin [DictField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#dictfield) or [ListField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield).

Ex:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    my_json_field = serializers.DictField()
```

It works fine, with `GET/PUT/PATCH/POST`, including with nested contents.

Comment: None of the above worked for me, but this one did.  Strange it is low on the list.  On the client side I had to pass  { "field": JSON.stringify(data), ... } with PATCH.  Default jquery $.ajax calls broke out every value into long keys like "field[key1][key2][etc]": value.

Answer (score 5):

serializers.WritableField is deprecated. This works:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from website.models import Picture


class PictureSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    json = serializers.SerializerMethodField('clean_json')

    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ('id', 'json')

    def clean_json(self, obj):
        return obj.json
```

Comment: Yes. If you have an object that you want to serialize you just need to read it. This will not modify the original object that you are serializing.

Answer (score 4):

Mark Chackerian script didn't work for me, I'd to force the json transform:

```
import json

class JSONSerializerField(serializers.Field):
    """ Serializer for JSONField -- required to make field writable"""

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        json_data = {}
        try:
            json_data = json.loads(data)
        except ValueError, e:
            pass
        finally:
            return json_data
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value
```

Works fine. Using DRF 3.15 and JSONFields in Django 1.8

Comment: And how you integrate this serializer field with model's JSONFields? Do you use ModelSerializer?

Comment: I use `serializers.Serializer`, but with `ModelSerializer` should works too

Comment: Noting that this does work with a `ModelSerializer` with DRF 3.2.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, this "just works" now if you are using PostgreSQL, and your model field is a`django.contrib.postgres.JSONField`.

I'm on PostgreSQL 9.4, Django 1.9, and Django REST Framework 3.3.2.

I have previously used several of the other solutions listed here, but was able to delete that extra code.

Example Model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid_nodash)
    data = JSONField(blank=True, default="")
```

Example Serializer:

```
class AccountSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id','data')
```

Example View:

```
class AccountViewSet(
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,      
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin
): 
    model = Account
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    filter_fields = ['id', 'data']
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks by the help. This is the code i finally use for render it

```
class JSONSerializerField(serializers.Field):
    """Serializer for JSONField -- required to make field writable"""

    def to_representation(self, value):
        json_data = {}
        try:
            json_data = json.loads(value)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise e
        finally:
            return json_data

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return json.dumps(data)

class AnyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field = JSONSerializerField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('field',)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mysql (haven't tried with other databases), using both DRF's new `JSONField` and Mark Chackerian's suggested  `JSONSerializerField` will save the json as a `{u'foo': u'bar'}` string.
If you rather save it as `{"foo": "bar"}`, this works for me:

```
import json

class JSONField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return json.loads(obj)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

> DRF gives us inbuilt field 'JSONField' for binary data, but JSON 
>   payload is verified only when you set 'binary' flag True then it convert into utf-8 and load the JSON payload, else it only
>   treat them as string(if invalid json is sent) or json and validate both
>   without error even though you cretaed JSONField

```
class JSONSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    serializer for JSON
    """
    payload = serializers.JSONField(binary=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

To serialize a data from a request you can use the serializers.ModelSerializer

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framwork import serializers
class FinalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model=Student
    fields='__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
import io
from yourappname.serializers import FinalSerializer #replace your app name
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser,MultiPartParser,FormParser
from rest_framework.response import Response


class DataList(APIView):


    parser_classes = (JSONParser,MultiPartParser,FormParser) #If you are using postman
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)
    #Serialize
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        all_data=Student.objects.all()
        serializer=FinalSerializer(all_data,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)#Will return serialized json data,makes sure you have data in your model
    #Deserialize
    #Not tried this function but it will work
    #from django documentation
    def djson(self,request,format=None):
        stream = io.BytesIO(json)
        data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
        serializer = FinalSerializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid()
        serializer.validated_data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want JSONField for mysql this is done in django-mysql and serializer was fixed some day ago [1], is not yet in any release.

[1] https://github.com/adamchainz/django-mysql/issues/353

## setting.py

add:

```
    'django_mysql',
```

## models.py

```
from django_mysql.models import JSONField

class Something(models.Model):
(...)
    parameters = JSONField()
```