# Django rest framework outputs JSONField with unicode prefix

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-unicode, django-jsonfield

In my api the output of JSONField looks like so:

```
"custom_content": "{u'key': u'value', u'hej': 1.992}",
```

Should be:

```
"custom_content": {"key": "value", "hej": 1.992},
```

I use djangorestframework==3.1.1, jsonfield==1.0.3, Django==1.7.4, python 2.7.6

Haven't had this problem in older projects. Any ideas to why this is happening now?

**UPDATE**

Solved with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28200902/632182

Comment: What does your serializer look like (include the `repr(TheSerializer())`)? It sounds like it's using a `CharField` instead of what you need.

Comment: Your comment made me think of the problem in a different way, and then solved the problem with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28200902/632182 Thanks a million :)