# Convert string array to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, django

I get the following item back from my django-rest-framework api call:

```
services = "['service1', 'service2', 'service3']"
```

I want `services = ['service1', 'service2', 'service3']`

In my JavaScript I tried `services = JSON.parse(services)`
- didn't do anything, also tried `$.parseJSON(services)`.

In my serializers I have tried the setting services as `ListField`, also tried `JSONSerializerField()`

```
class JSONSerializerField(serializers.Field):
    # Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/28200902
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return json.loads(data)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value
```

Comment: there's no assignments in JSON, just the data to the right of `=`, and it looks like the JSON should have `"` instead of `'` on the items, and not be over-all quoted.

Comment: Is `services` in your post a variable or part of the item you received?

Comment: its what i receive from my call. i am storing it as services = JSONField(blank=True, default=list) in my models. I will try the quote trick, think that might be the parse issue.

Comment: Don't try to create JSON using your own code. Use `json.dumps()`.

Answer (score 78):

To parse it you need to use double quotes instead of single.

This should work:

```
services = '["service1", "service2", "service3"]'
JSON.parse(services)
```

Comment: It works for me as well. Is there any intuition behind this? why the one with ' ' don't work?

Comment: Watch out for that trailing ` after the JSON.parse()

Comment: @FatemehRahimi the one with `''` don't work because JSON recognize only `""` for strings

Comment: I did a services.replaceAll('\'', '"') --- 
note 2nd one has " within the enclosing '

Answer (score 13):

This is used to convert string which is array into pure array

```
var a = '[Aakash,akash]'
a.replace(/\[|\]/g,'').split(',')
(2) ["Aakash", "akash"]
```

Comment: Do you mind to explain what this `/\[|\]/g` means ?

Comment: Kai...Life saver

Comment: @Nizzam
  let string = "[2, 4, 5, 7]";
  let array = string.replace(/\[|\]/g, "").split(", ");

/\[|\]/g is a regexp to remove the "[" and "]" in the string

Comment: looks like escaping string concept. appreciate your reply. thanks.

Comment: @Nizzam its a regular expression - \ is escape character like you said, the | means or, and /g at the end means global - a replace all.

However the OP's example already has single quotes in it.

Answer (score 11):

Your response is of the form

```
services = "['service1', 'service2', 'service3']"
```

JSON.parse() will work if the parent quote is a single quote and all other child quotes are double quotes. I have quoted an example below

```
services = '["service1", "service2", "service3"]'
```

We can use replace() to achieve this
Here is a working example

```
services = "['service1', 'service2', 'service3']"
services = services.replace(/'/g, '"') //replacing all ' with "
services = JSON.parse(services)
console.log(services)
```

Comment: Also, if you have trailing comma in your array, make sure to remove it or error will be thrown: `.replace(/,]$/, ']')`

Answer (score 3):

To ensure correct parsing between Django and some javascript browser code, be sure that you return a JsonResponse() in your controller. This ensures you can parse it with JSON.parse() in your Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

**Try Using:**

```js
var services = "['service1', 'service2', 'service3']"
services = services .split(",");
services [0] = services [0].substring(1);
services [services .length - 1] = services [services .length - 1].substring(
  0,
  services [services .length - 1].length - 1
);
services .forEach((x, i) => {
  services [i] = services [i].includes('"') ? services [i].replaceAll('"', "").trim()
     : services [i].replaceAll("'", "").trim();
});

console.log(services );
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently found a roundabout way of solving a similar problem. I wanted to store an array as a data attribute in an HTML element so that I could use it later in the JS. However, such an HTML attribute could only be stored as a string. To solve this...

1. First I turned the arrays into a single string, with each value separated by a comma (ex. `["test 1", "test 2", "test 3"]` is written as `“test 1,test 2,test 3”`).
2. Next, I entered the new string into the desired HTML data attribute. (ex. `<div data-somedata="test 1,test 2,test 3"></div>`)
3. Upon entering the JS, I retrieved that data string and converted it back into an array by using jQuery's "split” method. For this check out the snippet here.

```js
let stillString = $("[data-something]").attr('data-something');
console.log(stillString);

let nowArray = stillString.split(",");
console.log(nowArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div data-something="test 1,test 2,test 3"></div>
```

This may not look pretty, keeping an array as a string, but it gets the job done and your average users won't know the difference.

**NOTE**: You don't HAVE to use commas. You could use any character really. The only thing that matters that none of the values that you're trying to separate contain the character that you chose split them with.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps

1. let arr = new Array(services);
2. let servicesArray = JSON.parse(arr[0]);

By these two steps you array "['service1', 'service2', 'service3']" would be converted to this one ['service1', 'service2', 'service3']

Answer (score 0):

```
var services = "['service1', 'service2', 'service3']";

// --- You can use JavaScript Default function for that
var dataArray = JSON.parse(services.replace(/'/g, '"')); 
// --- .replace(/'/g, '"') we use this to convert double quotes to single because in JSON we use double Quotes

dataArray.forEach(service => {
    console.log(service);
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

## eval

Warning: SUPER DANGEROUS. Don't pass unsanitized input.

```js
> services = "['service1', 'service2', 'service3']"
> eval(services)

Array(3) [ "service1", "service2", "service3" ]
```