# Read an array from a cell

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently I have a cell containing an array, eg A1 has [1,2,3]. I managed to get the value from the cell and tried to turn it into an array but it’s not working. Is it possible?

```
arrValue = cellValue // cell that was pass to the function, eg [1,2,3]
arr = Array(arrValue)
Logger.log(arr[0]) // prints [1,2,3]
```

Comment: As the additional information, if `[1,2,3]` is put in a cell and you retrieve the value using `getValue` and `getValues`, the retrieved value is the string type. So in this case, the value is `"[1,2,3]"`. In your script, when `arr = Array("[1,2,3]")` is used, `arr` is `["[1,2,3]"]`. So `arr[0]` returns `[1,2,3]`. In this case, `[1,2,3]` is `"[1,2,3]"` which is the string. I think that the reason of `Logger.log(arr[0]) // prints [1,2,3]` is due to this. Also please be careful this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string array to array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402834/convert-string-array-to-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a [valid json string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), use `JSON.parse`:

```js
const jsonArr = /*cellValue*/ '[1,2,3]';
const arr = JSON.parse(jsonArr);
console.info({isArray: Array.isArray(arr),length:arr.length,element_1:arr[0]})
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `cellValue` is in fact gotten as a string, then of course the answer you will be getting is the whole array.

What you can do instead is to declare your values as an array, like this:

```
 var arrValue = [1,2,3]
 var arr = arrValue;
 Logger.log(arr[0]) // prints 1.0
```