# Is it possible to pass array command line arguments nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a script and to launch with yarn like this :

```
yarn start arg1, arg2, arg3
```

it's work fine, I recover all arguments in :

```
  const args = process.argv.slice(2);
```

But if I want to do :

```
yarn start arg1, arg2, arg3, ['option1', 'option2']
```

it's not work, I got an error :

```
zsh: no matches found: [option1]
```

I need an array of options sometimes and args can be infinite

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`process.argv` will contain all arguments you pass, no matter how many there are.

The error you're getting is from your shell (zsh), not Node or Yarn – you need to quote arguments that have special characters such as `[]`:

```
yarn start arg1 arg2 arg3 "['option1', 'option2']"
```

– here's a small example program to show the output:

```
/tmp $ echo 'console.log(process.argv)' > args.js
/tmp $ node args.js arg1 arg2 arg3 "['option1', 'option2']"
[
  '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/tmp/args.js',
  'arg1',
  'arg2',
  'arg3',
  "['option1', 'option2']"
]
```

Comment: How can you parse this string "['option1', 'option2']" into array?

Answer (score 0):

I had same basic question - this pointed me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41402909/826308

In my case I also needed to get to an array even if JSON.parse() failed so I used this:

```
function stringToArray(str){
    var arr = [];
    if(str.indexOf('[',0) > -1 && str.indexOf(']',0) > -1){
    arr = JSON.parse(str);
  }else{
    arr.push(str);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can you parse this string "['option1', 'option2']" into array?

I don't have 50 reputation to answer Matt, however you can easily parse this array by surrounding it with JSON.parse.

Example:

```
    //assuming first argument (after the filename) will be an array
var argArray;
process.argv.forEach(function (arg, index, array)
{
        switch (index)
        {
                case 2:
                        argArray = arg;
        }
})

console.log(typeof(argArray), " var: ", argArray);

console.log(typeof(JSON.parse(argArray)), " var: ", argArray);
```

If you use this with an array argument written as such: `"[\"test\", \"test\"]"`
you should get the following output from this program:

```
string  var:  ["test", "test"]
object  var:  ["test", "test"]
```

As you can see the string-formatted-array parsed as a JSON-string gets converted to an object which can be treated like an array.