# how to remove quotation marks around array in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-visualization

I processed a data in python and saved the file in JSON format.

However, I ran into a problem after getting the JSON file when I use them in node.js
which is

the JSON file looks like as below.

```
{
    "title": "Christmas Eggnog",
    "ingredients": "['whites', 'yolks', 'sugar', 'rye', 'whiskey', 'brandy', 'rum', 'cream']",
    "id": "05zEpbSqcs9E0rcnCJWyZ9OgdH0MLby"
},
```

The ingredients has to be a normal array however, it is an array held by quotation marks.
And it eventually makes it impossible to read this json file as intended.

```
{
    "title": "Christmas Eggnog",
    "ingredients": ["whites", "yolks", "sugar", "rye", "whiskey", "brandy", "rum", "cream"],
    "id": "05zEpbSqcs9E0rcnCJWyZ9OgdH0MLby"
},
```

I would like to get the log value like below. When I read this JSON file in node.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let predata = fs.readFileSync('./data/testonce.json')
let data = JSON.parse(predata)
let newData = [];
data.forEach((d) => {
    newData.push((d) => {
        let targetarray = d.ingredients.split(',')
        return {...d, ingredients: targetarray }
    })
})

console.log(newData[0])
//"whites"
```

I can't get the string "white" because node doesn't understand the fact that
`"['whites', 'yolks', 'sugar', 'rye', 'whiskey', 'brandy', 'rum', 'cream']"` is an array.
Node sees it as one long string.

How do I turn this string into a normal array?

Edit)

My python code is as below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')

ingredients = df['ingredients']

for i in range(len(ingredients)):
    ingredients[i]=str(ingredients[i])[1:-1]

ingredients

df['ingredients']=ingredients

df.to_csv ('./datatest.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

After this, I used csv->json formatter in this website.
[https://csvjson.com/[![enter](https://csvjson.com/%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beKCY.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beKCY.png)

Edit)

this is the csv file link

we.tl/t-Kw435qpNNd

It looks like this[image]

Edit) Sample csv text
This is the sample csv text.

title,ingredients,id
Christmas Eggnog ,"['whites', 'yolks', 'sugar', 'rye', 'whiskey', 'brandy', 'rum', 'cream']",05zEpbSqcs9E0rcnCJWyZ9OgdH0MLby
"Veal, Carrot and Chestnut Ragoût ","['chestnuts', 'veal', 'stew', 'meat', 'oil', 'onion', 'garlic', 'leaf', 'salt', 'chicken broth', 'wine', 'carrots', 'sage']",mF5SZmoqxF4WtIlhLRvzuKk.z6s7P2S
Caramelized Bread Pudding with Chocolate and Cinnamon ,"['butter', 'brioche', 'quality', 'bread', 'crusts', 'eggs', 'egg', 'yolks', 'brown', 'sugar', 'cream', 'milk', 'vanilla', 'cinnamon', 'nutmeg', 'kosher salt', 'chocolate', 'top']",oQV5D7cVbCFwmrDs3pBUv2y.AG0WV26
Sherried Stilton and Green Peppercorn Spread ,"['stilton', 'cream cheese', 'peppercorns', 'brine', 'sherry']",Z9seBJWaB5NkSp4DQHDnCAUBTwov/1u
Almond-Chocolate Macaroons ,"['almonds', 'sugar', 'cinnamon', 'salt', 'egg', 'almond', 'semisweet', 'chocolate']",bB3GxoAplVZeoX3fzWNWyeECtQFxw6G
White Sauce or Bechamel Sauce ,"['butter', 'flour', 'milk', 'salt', 'pepper']",FHQAJvovVtPyKWlzgFEHgSUJsCM2Tjq

Comment: please add the python code that produces the json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an Object {} to an Array \[\] of key-value pairs in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824349/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript)

Comment: The real problem is in the code that created this 'faulty' JSON, so this is the part to correct.

Comment: @LelioFaieta No...

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia I added my python code thank you

Comment: @BS100 check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41402909/4155792

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string array to array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402834/convert-string-array-to-array-in-javascript)

Comment: based on the line:`ingredients[i]=str(ingredients[i])[1:-1]`, it appears the problem is in the csv data itself. could you also add a sample of the csv file?

Comment: please add the sample file as the text so it be useful to run the code locally and not the image. anyway, if you remove the `str` from the above line and just do `ingredients[i]=ingredients[i][1:-1]`, does it give the expected result?

Comment: The clean thing to do would be to read your original CSV with Python, convert the string in the ingredients field that represents a list to a real list with `ast.literal_eval()` from the `ast` module of the standard library, and to save it directly as JSON with Python, using the standard `json` module.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia I added sample csv as text Thank you

Comment: so, it looks like the csv itself has the problem where ingredients are present as string, have a look at this thread: [how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

because its a string, you need to strip of the bad bits you do not want, and then convert what is left of the string into an array

```
var list = "['whites', 'yolks', 'sugar', 'rye', 'whiskey', 'brandy', 'rum', 'cream']".replace(/[\[\]["',]/g,'').split(" ");
```

The replace uses regex to remove the " ' , [ ]  characters, and the split cuts up the string by the remaining spaces and converts it into an array.

```
console.log(list);
0: "whites"
1: "yolks"
2: "sugar"
3: "rye"
4: "whiskey"
5: "brandy"
6: "rum"
7: "cream"
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Thierry Lathuille to fix the problem in the producer.  If you you want to patch it up here, I would parse the string as JSON and just replace it:

```
data.forEach(r => {
    r.ingredients = JSON.parse(r.ingredients);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const json = {
    "title": "Christmas Eggnog",
    "ingredients": "['whites', 'yolks', 'sugar', 'rye', 'whiskey', 'brandy', 'rum', 'cream']",
    "id": "05zEpbSqcs9E0rcnCJWyZ9OgdH0MLby"
}

const ingredients = json.ingredients.substr(1, json.ingredients.length -2)
const ingredientsList = ingredients.split(', ').map(item => item.substr(1, item.length -2))



console.log(ingredientsList)
```