# JavaScript - Converting string-array to an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have the following input which I receive:

```js
const myString = "['one', 'two']";
```

When I run the following command:

```js
console.log(typeof myString);
```

I get `string`

This makes sense, as this is a string input. The input type is out of my control, I must receive this as a typeof string.

However, I would like to convert this string, into a formal array of strings.

For example:

```js
const myArray = ['one', 'two'];
```

So, when I run:

```js
console.log(typeof myArray);
```

I get `object`.

I have tried `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify` but to no luck.

The basics of my question are how do I (in JavaScript) convert a string array, into an array of strings?

Comment: An array is an object

Comment: `JSON.parse()` would work if `myString` is a valid JSON string (double quotes around your elements, not single quotes - `'["one", "two"]'`)

Comment: maybe something interesting to read, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model)

Comment: Yea as @NickParsons said, you can replaceAll `'` with `"` if you don't control the input and then it just becomes this answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402834/convert-string-array-to-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.parse` *would* work, if the JSON wasn't invalid. As mentioned in the comments, the string would have to be formatted as `'["1", "2"]'`.

If you do not have control over the formatting, you can parse it manually: if the strings don't contain quotes, you can use `#replaceAll("'", '"')`.

If you have edge cases you need to cover, [json5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5) may be able to help: `JSON5.parse(str)` once you have the script loaded via NPM or unpkg

Answer (score 1):

JSON only recognizes the usage of `" "`. To [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```js
const myString = "['one', 'two']"; 
// change to
const myString = '["one", "two"]';
```

Heres an example:

```js
// Not working
const Str = "['one', 'two']";

console.log(Str); // ['one', 'two']
console.log(typeof Str); // string

JSON.parse(Str); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

// Working example:
const myString = '["one", "two"]';

console.log(myString); // ["one", "two"]
console.log(typeof myString); // string

const myArray = JSON.parse(myString);

console.log(myArray); // [ 'one', 'two' ]
console.log(typeof myArray); // object
```

In the case that you need to change `'` to `"` just use [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
const myArray = ['one', 'two'];
let str = myArray.toString();
console.log(str);//one,two
console.log(typeof str)//string
let srr = str.split(",");
console.log(srr);//[ 'one', 'two' ]
console.log(typeof srr)//object same as that of myArray
```

The above variable myArray is holding an array . In order to convert the array into string there is an inbuilt method in myArray.toString().
Now to convert array to string we will use split method as shown above.