# How to a serialize model field that holds raw JSON?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Supposing I have a field in my model that stores raw JSON (so containing double quotes, `null`, `false` etc.):

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    textjson = models.TextField(default="Unassigned")
```

how do I serialize this model so that the API response will not contain backslashes, the sign of double serialization?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Rest Framework and JSONField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434869/django-rest-framework-and-jsonfield)

Comment: I have tried this answer before posting, but did not help.

Comment: Share your serialization code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PostrgeSQL so you can use JSONFIeld to avoid serialization. To convert raw text to JSON use

```
json.loads(string)
```

or to get string from json

```
json.dumps(json)
```

Comment: `segment_efforts` is dumped already - it is raw JSON text. The serializer turns it to text again and backslashes appear. And `json.loads` gives Python object, not text.

Comment: loads() returns dict. As it written above. Which serializer adds slashes to text?